# JavaScript show.uk.modal load iframe

Tags: javascript

I am using http://getuikit.com/docs/modal.html on my site,
and want to load iframe when user click button using show.uk.modal and hide.uk.modal, but i am big noob in JavaScript.
I am trying this

```
<a class="md-btn  md-btn-primary  md-btn-small md-btn-wave-light md-btn-icon waves-effect waves-button waves-light" id="iframe" data-uk-modal="{target:'#split4'}">
<i class="uk-icon-map"></i>
  Split
 </a>
```

This is wrong or i am doing some mistake.

```
<div class="uk-modal DOrefresh" id="split4">
            <div class="uk-modal-dialog uk-modal-dialog-large">
        <script>
            $('#split4').on('show.uk.modal',function(){ 
                $(this).find('iframe').attr('src','/software/forms_mini.php')
            });


        </script>
            </div>
        </div>
```

Comment: Should `shown.uk.modal` maybe be `show.uk.modal` instead?

Comment: Sorry typing mistake ;) .. but its not working ... do i have to add <iframe> ... or some thing ?